# Duplicate key xxx (attempted merging values) Hybris giving error after upgradation

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am facing issue with updating some of the users after upgrading hybris from 6.5 to 2205.11.

```
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.ModelSavingException: Duplicate key xxxx (attempted merging values de.hybris.platform.directpersistence.cache.SLDDataContainer$AttributeValue@3443c8aa[name=xxx,value=<null>,langPk=8796093055008] and de.hybris.platform.directpersistence.cache.SLDDataContainer$AttributeValue@7829be1f[name=xxx,value=<null>,langPk=8796093513760])
```

I went through the below links:

https://me.sap.com/notes/0003211013

https://answers.sap.com/questions/13291626/duplicate-key-error-when-saving-a-customer-in-sap.html

But when querying userprops table, I am not able to get any result.
I am not able to update users via code, impex(hac) or even backoffice.
Any suggestions or feedbacks are most welcomed.